# Here's pictogram #8

Tags: visual, rebus

Not enough of these and we're in trouble!

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The answer is

> [Antibodies](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Antibody) (Ant + Eye + Bodies)

Comment: Yes (lightning brain there!), but I have to wait 12 min. to check it.